# pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: mongodb

When i faced his error i deleted mongod.lock from /var/lib/mongodb 
then i did mongod -repair
SO it listed all these things

```
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21182 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=thara-Precision-T1600
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] git version: 52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc62057db386e4e029c
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 dbexit: 
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Mar 21 14:21:17.511 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Still it says pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Answer (score 4):

Like it says in the error message, mongod is not able to find the db path.  Either create the folder `"/data/db"` at the root or if you have created it else where, specify the path using the [`--dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/) option like:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

Comment: In the /etc/mongodb.conf file the dbpath= /var/lib/mongodb and logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log which i changed to another directory datapath=/data/db and logpath=/data/log .

Comment: I hope you meant "dbpath" rather than "datapath".  Also, does the folder "/data/db" exist?

Comment: and how are you starting mongod?  are you passing the required params for the mongodb.conf to be used? i.e., `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` or `mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf`